# Bulk insert records and get their Id's after bulk insert in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to bulk insert 100,000+ rows into a table (which has a identity column which auto increments every time a new row is inserted).

1. What would be the fastest way to insert the rows with least performance impact?
2. After all rows are inserted, how do I get the list of ids of the rows that are recently inserted?

Note: I did the following but I did not get the list of ids

```
ctx.Documents.AddRange(documentsList);
ctx.SaveChanges();

var ids = documentsList.Select(d => d.Id);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Bulk Insert` in Entity Framework. You must use a third-party library to perform this kind of operation.

By default, Entity Framework will make a database round-trip for every entity to save. So more than 100,000 database round-trip will be required in your scenario which is **INSANELY** slow.

---

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library is not free but allows you to perform all bulk operations including `BulkInsert` and return automatically the `Id's`. You can also insert related entity with `IncludeGraph` options:

- Bulk SaveChanges
- Bulk Insert
- Bulk Delete
- Bulk Update
- Bulk Merge

Example

```
// Easy to use
context.BulkSaveChanges();

// Easy to customize
context.BulkSaveChanges(bulk => bulk.BatchSize = 100);

// Perform Bulk Operations
context.BulkDelete(customers);
context.BulkInsert(customers);
context.BulkUpdate(customers);

// Customize Primary Key
context.BulkMerge(customers, operation => {
   operation.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = 
        customer => customer.Code;
});
```

**EDIT:** Answer questions

> Are those the same bits as "EF Plus"

I'm also the owner of [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

In short, we split free and paid features into two libraries. EF+ doesn't support `Bulk Operations`.

The only features both libraries currently share is `Batch Delete` and `Batch Update`

Comment: Are those the same bits as "EF Plus" (http://entityframework-plus.net/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Another library can do this now as well:
https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions

It achieves it using the SetOutputIdentity BulkConfig option.  After insertion the C# objects in your list will have the IDs set to the values generated by the database.  Under the hood BulkExtensions also uses an efficient bulk copy implementation so that insertion is fast.